# How to distinguish between overloads of a templated function

Tags: templates, metaprogramming, d

Assigning a non-templated function to a variable of type `function` selects the
right overload based on the signature:

```d
// OK
void fn(int val) {}
void fn(int val, int val2) {}

void function(int) foo = &fn;
```

However, I can't seem to do the same with a templated function:

```d
// template fn!2 matches more than one template declaration
void fn2(T)(T val) {}
void fn2(T)(T val, T val2) {}

void function(int) foo2 = &fn2!int;
```

If I could just expand `fn2!int`, it seems like it would be equivalent to the
first case.

Is there any way to get the overload of `fn2` that I want?
Note that this is declared at the module level, so I cannot (as far as I know)
use `__traits(getOverloads)`.

Comment: Right now I'm using the hacky solution of declaring `void _fn2(T)(T val)` that just forwards to the single-parameter overload of `fn2`.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround for this is to declare the two functions inside the same template declaration, instead of using eponymous tempalates:

```d
template fn(T)
{
    void fn(T a) { }
    void fn(T a, T b) { }
}

void main()
{
    void function(int) ptr1 = &fn!int;
    void function(int, int) ptr2 = &fn!int;
}
```

Comment: I guess I'll have to go with this. It does change the way the documentation is generated but that's not a huge deal. I do wonder if this could affect template bloat at all -- will `fn!int` generate multiple functions instead of one if I only ever use the first overload?

Comment: Instantiating the template `fn` will generate both functions, so if only one is used, then you will experience some amount of template bloat, yes. I should also note that a similar issue has been [reported before](https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=337). There are some alternate workarounds shown there.